# Change image source every n seconds wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation

I need to chage image on windows phone 7 app every 25ms. This animation should start after button pressed and play for 10 seconds. Is there any way to do it in wp7?

Comment: I expect that rate is too high. Are all the images already on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

on the button click event you could create a timer object and start it, then on the timers tick event you check to see whether the current millisecond reading on the timer is divisible by exactly 25 (use the modulo operator) if it is you can then run the code that will change the image source property, and in the same tick event handler you can set a check for if the second reading is 10 seconds, and if it is stop the timer